# Command line interface using Python subprocess

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I have a program with a command line interface that I need to control with Python.  When I launch the program from a Windows command prompt, it initially responds with a welcome message.  Then I enter a command and it responds to that command, etc. The example below is one of my attempts to accomplish this with Python.

```
cli = ["vqtcli", "10.0.0.19"]
cmd = "status"
p = subprocess.Popen(cli, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print p.communicate(input=cmd)
```

The initial welcome message is expected in response to the vqtcli command and a different output is expected in response to the status command, but what gets printed in this example is just the welcome message.  How do I get a response to the status command?

Comment: are you sure `vqtcli` expects its input from standard input streams and prints its responses to the standard output? (it may work with the console directly). Your `print` should print a tuple. Do you see it?

Comment: Yes, it works with the console using standard input and output, and the print output is a tuple.

Comment: Have you tried `stderr=PIPE`?

Comment: Ok, I tried stderr=PIPE and it did not make any difference.

Comment: If you run in the console `vqtcli 10.0.0.19 <input_file >output_file`  where `input_file` contains `status`; do you see the expected output in the `output_file`?

Comment: It doesn't work that way.  However, I just found that 'vqtcli 10.0.0.19 status' works in the console and returns the correct responses to both the vqtcli command and the status command.  However, after that it becomes unresponsive for 20 seconds and then exits.  Using popen, it waits 20 seconds before it returns anything (waiting for EOF maybe?).  If there was a way to get the responses prior to the 20 second timeout, then this might be usable, but both 'p.communicate()' and 'p.stdout.read()' wait until after the timeout.

Comment: If it doesn't work in the console then the code in the question won't work either. Do you understand the difference between the standard input stream (stdin) and the command-line arguments (argv)? Update your question and provide a *working* console command. If you don't want to wait until the command exits by itself then you have to specify some other exit criteria e.g., "exit  in 5 seconds" or  "read until ***".